# dotenv module not found error pythonanywhere

Tags: flash, dotenv

I have a pythonanywhere flask application setup. Everything works fine except for dotenv. I installed it using pip install python-dotenv on python 3.7 while my virtual environment was activated. I still get the module not found error though. Any solutions?

Comment: Where are you seeing the error message -- in a console, or in the website's error logs?  Or somewhere else?

Comment: In the error logs. When I load up the virtual environment in a bash console and run the var/www/my_web_app.py file it runs fine no errors.

Comment: Are you sure that your web app is configured to run in that virtual environment? What do you see in the "Virtualenv" section of your "Web" configuration page on PythonAnywhere?

Comment: yea. It works now turns out I had to import dotenv in the var/www/www_my_web_app_wsgi.py file and load the environment variables from then and from my app.py use os.getenv to access them. Everything works perfect now. Could this be marked as an answer to my own question?

Comment: I think that you can post it as an answer in the box below these comments and then mark it as the official answer yourself

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I had to import dotenv in the var/www/www_my_web_app_wsgi.py file and load the environment variables from then and from my app.py use os.getenv to access them. Everything works perfect now.